# Blazor Web Assembly Standalone OIDC

Tags: .net, cors, blazor, openid-connect

I'm trying to call OIDC, ID.Me, to handle Authorization.

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

        ...

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("IDMe", options.ProviderOptions); 
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("openid");
        });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
```

https://developers.id.me/documentation/federated-protocols/oidc

Within my wwwroot/appsettings.Development.json I have the following:

```
"IDMe": {
    "Authority": "https://api.idmelabs.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&scope={openid SCOPE}&state=optional",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:44370/authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44370/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
```

When I attempt to do this I get a CORs Error.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.idmelabs.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={XXXXXX}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7044&response_type=code&scope=military&state=optional/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'https://localhost:7044' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Is there a way to get this CORS error to go away on my local? I only see solutions for a server.

Comment: The CORS error is because you can't use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` to request tokens or authenticate the user - that needs to be a top-level browser document request.

Comment: @Dai I don't follow, isn't that what AddOidcAuthentication is for?

Comment: What is is at `https://localhost:7044` and how does that differ from what's at `https://localhost:44370`?

Comment: Should have all been `https://localhost:7044` instead of 44370 @Dai `44370` is my Azure functions.

Comment: Simply you need to redirect to ``Authorize`` URL not calling it by ``XMLHttpRequest ``

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate access to an API here? In that case you need to add `app.UseCors()` with some policy options to the program.cs of the API app. But this is just a wild guess :)

Comment: @RolandDeschain no I'm trying to auth a Blazor Web Assembly Standalone website via an OIDC

Comment: @sa-es-ir ok so if i use it as a hyperlink and let it use the redirect back to me with a code how will i use that code to authorize the blazor app?